Why is {_Integer..} matching {_Rule..}?
Why is this getting stuck in a loop:
PitchCycle[{length_Integer,order_Integer:1,offset_Integer:0},octave_:"",pitches_:All,modulations:{_Rule..}:{1->0},properties___:All]:=
    PitchCycle[{length,order,offset},octave,pitches,Normal@SparseArray[modulations,{length}],properties];

Calling:
PitchCycle[{14, 1, 0}, 4, {1, 3, 4}, {1 -> 2}]

Results in:

TerminatedEvaluation["IterationLimit"]

After doing Normal of SparseArray I should be getting {_Integer..} which shouldn't match {_Rule..}. I don't understand the evaluation. I must be doing something stupid. Please help!

[Begin rant] Using default values in your argument list (the second : in patterns) as well as using ___ for optional arguments (which is what I'm assuming you're doing with properties), are both very bad ideas. Pattern matching on arguments is actually quite a tricky business once you add in these constructs, and I've just never found a case where it's worth it. There are better alternatives. [End rant]
Since you gave modulations a default value (specifically {1 -> 0}) then in the call to
PitchCycle[{14, 1, 0}, 4, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]

The pattern matcher indeed found no list of rules, but it was able to match that final list of integers and bind it to properties. With a missing modulations argument, it used the default value.
Note
FWIW, a simpler pattern for {_Rule ..} would be just {__Rule}.
Clarification
When I say they are "very bad ideas" I'm not making a universal claim about default values and optional arguments. I do think that those are generally sloppy, but not always "very bad ideas". I'm saying that they are "very bad ideas" specifically in the context of trying to get Mathematica to parse your arguments as expected. The semantics might seem clear, but the implementation that the pattern matcher uses to parse arguments has many subtleties around these specific constructs that very easily lead to unexpected behavior. This specific case is only a minor example, and not a particularly "hairy" one. Things can get much more "weird" than this.

I thought it matches left to right, no? How can it match {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} to properties if modulation isn't matched first.

Because, you gave it an "out" with the default value.

BTW, I didn't really "help" in terms of showing how to make it work. If your "properties" argument is something like an Options setting, then you'd be better off using OptionsPattern. Or if you don't want to do that, it would help to add any constraint to "properties" so that it doesn't match a list of integers. Then the pattern matcher will be unable to discover any match.

Here is an example to show why the "left to right" assumption is incorrect: MatchQ[{"a"}, {_Integer : 0, _String : "-"}] gives True. Even though _Integer came first, the matcher "looked ahead" and noticed that "a" matched _String and so with the default value for the integer, it could make a match.

@user13892, lericr: Isn't MatchQ[{"a"}, {_Integer : 0, _String : "-"}] better explained thus: First, it matches the head List. Then the matcher tries to match "a" to _Integer, which fails; but it is Optional, so success with no lookahead; the expression scan stays put at "a", and the pattern scan moves right. Next, the matcher tries to match "a" to _String, which succeeds. Now we're done and the result is True. Thus this case can be explained with left-to-right scans.

@MichaelE2 Maybe that's a better explanation. I guess I've used "look-ahead" non-rigorously. But the point is that "a" matched _String. When the OP said "left-to-right" they meant it in a way that expected the matcher to fail the test when comparing the list of integers to {__Rule}. But the matcher had "more stuff to look at" to be able to conclude that the test was successful. That's what I meant by "look-ahead". Maybe it's better to say that Optional always results in a tentative intermediate match?

@MichaelE2 I guess my misuse of "look-ahead" is parallel to the OP's misuse of "left-to-right" scan. We should rewrite the entire discussion from scratch.

@MichaelE2 Consider this example: MatchQ[{1, ""}, {_Integer : 0, _, _String}]. This returns True. Strictly left-to-right, the 1 would have successfully matched the _Integer, and then we would go on to fail the overall test. So, even though the matcher had a perfectly good match at the leftmost, non-head opportunity, it didn't "commit" to that. I guess I think of that as "look-ahead".

@MichaelE2 The exact same opportunity for a match occurs here: MatchQ[{1, 1, ""}, {_Integer : 0, _, _String}] and this time it eventually is forced to commit to it. I know nothing about the underlying implementation, but there must be some sort of statefulness involved that allows the matcher to resolve previous (more left) tentative matches after discovering subsequent (more right) information.

I think of it combinatorially. _Integer : 0 is two alternatives, with _Integer being the first attempted match and then the default filling in for no match. (The default value seems a red herring in MatchQ[]; it's really Optional[] that is at work.) When more than one argument has alternatives, each combination is generated left to right like nested loops, and the first to succeed is the match. Actually, I think of it as doing an expression tree traversal. I've picked this up from experience and conversations, it's probably wrong here and there, and I do not an authoritative reference.

@MichaelE2 The default just made it easier to see what's going on. Doesn't really help with MatchQ specifically, but I put those same patterns into some function where I can "log" the bindings. Yeah, I think an expression tree is probably a good analogy.

The underlying point here (for me anyway), is that these types of patterns get very difficult to understand very quickly. One default/optional at the end of an argument list doesn't usually cause problems. Start mixing them in elsewhere, and start adding BlankNullSequences into the mix, and all of a sudden Mathematica's match decisions, while rigorously defined, start deviating from what most users intend their argument patterns to "mean". Also, there are (or were anyway) known defects with optional/default that just make the whole strategy fraught for no good design reason.

My point was a side issue, that the processing could be done left-to-right (and I feel it probably is); however, the OP was mistaken how it was done with regard to {_Rule ..} :.... As for your point in the "rant," I mainly agree. I use optional and blank-repeated patterns often, but I usually avoid having more than one such pattern. Keeping straight how the combinations work quickly becomes difficult, and I don't want to make it hard for me to understand my own code.

@user13892 I would echo lericr's recommendation of using options, when one has many optional arguments. I think of it as somewhat like named arguments in Python. The order of (distinct) options does not matter, and good option names document what the arguments are at the point of the function call — a relief to the programmer.
